# Variable Appendendage Printing Literal String

Tags: powershell

I have a variable `$emp` and an individual folder variable for each employee in this variable.  So I have 1) `$GeorgeFullSaveDir` and 2) `$JamesFullSaveDir`. Using a `foreach` loop I iterate the values of `$emp` in order to reduce/re-use code is it possible to not create an individual variable for each employees savedir and append the value of `$emp` to FullSaveDir?
I have unsuccessfully tried the below

```
$employees = @('George', 'James')
foreach ($emp in $employees)
{
    $SaveDirRoot = "R:\Employees\"
    $GeorgeSaveDir = "George\"
    $JamesSaveDir = "James\"
    $GeorgeFullSaveDir = $SaveDirRoot+$GeorgeSaveDir
    $JamesFullSaveDir = $SaveDirRoot+$JamesSaveDir

    Write-Host $emp+FullSaveDir
    #Desired output will be
    #R:\Employees\George\ 
    #R:\Employees\James\
}
```

Further explenation - for each iteration of the variable `$emp` I want to be able to append `$emp+FullSaveDir` and produce the results for that specific employee.  So with the current syntax it would produce

> 1) R:\Employees\George\
>   2) R:\Employees\James\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Get-Variable` cmdlet to refer variable by its name:

```
$employees = 'George', 'James'
$SaveDirRoot = "R:\Employees\"
$GeorgeSaveDir = "George\"
$JamesSaveDir = "James\"
$GeorgeFullSaveDir = $SaveDirRoot+$GeorgeSaveDir
$JamesFullSaveDir = $SaveDirRoot+$JamesSaveDir

foreach ($emp in $employees)
{
    Write-Host (Get-Variable ($emp+'FullSaveDir') -ValueOnly)
}
```

But, IMHO, instead of using multiple variable per employee you should store all employee related information in one object:

```
$employees = @(
    @{
        Name = 'George'
        SaveDir = "George\"
    }
    @{
        Name = 'James'
        SaveDir = "James\"
    }
)
$SaveDirRoot = "R:\Employees\"

foreach ($emp in $employees)
{
    $emp.FullSaveDir = $SaveDirRoot+$emp.SaveDir
}

foreach ($emp in $employees)
{
    Write-Host $emp.FullSaveDir
}
```

Comment: I never thought about storing the data in an object, what a great solution